# Can I make one select statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, relational-database

```
SELECT Count(*) AS MonthTotal
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016'

SELECT Count(*) AS YearTotal
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'

SELECT Count(*) AS MonthNew
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016'
AND SystemType = 'O'

SELECT Count(*) AS YearClosed
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'
AND SystemType = 'C'
```

It only populates the month in the table, it does not populate the other sections as Visual studio does not allow multiple select statements for one data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT 'Month Total' AS Label, Count(*) AS Value
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Year Total' AS Label, Count(*) AS Value
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Month New' AS Label, Count(*) AS Value
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016'
AND SystemType = 'O'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Year Closed' AS Label, Count(*) AS Value
FROM CRMProjects
WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'
AND SystemType = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM(CASE)` as a kind of `SUMIF` for this...

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016' THEN 1 END) AS MonthTotal,
    SUM(1)    AS YearTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016' AND SystemType = 'O' THEN 1 END) AS MonthNew,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SystemType = 'C' THEN 1 END)    AS YearClosed
FROM
    CRMProjects
WHERE
    CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'
```

This ensures that you only scan the relevant section of the table once, aggregating the results in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

Select each count as a column of its own:

```
Select 
    (SELECT Count(*) 
       FROM CRMProjects
      WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016') AS MonthTotal,


    (SELECT Count(*) 
       FROM CRMProjects
      WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016') AS YearTotal,


    (SELECT Count(*)
       FROM CRMProjects
      WHERE CreatedDate between '01 May 2016' and '31 May 2016'
        AND SystemType = 'O')  AS MonthNew,


    (SELECT Count(*) 
       FROM CRMProjects
      WHERE CreatedDate between '01 Jan 2016' and '31 Dec 2016'
        AND SystemType = 'C') AS YearClosed
```